# Getting an error message "java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation..."

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error, java.util.scanner

What's the error in the following codes? I can't find an error. But am getting an error message saying:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at CircleArea.main(CircleArea.java:6)
```

The code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleArea{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
     Scanner inputFromUser = new Scanner (System.in);
     int radius = inputFromUser.nextInt();

     double Area =Math.PI *radius*radius;

     System.out.println("Area of the circle is : " + Area);
   }     
 }
```

Comment: As a general rule, if you say you're getting an error message, TELL US what the error message is.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment which asks you to find the error? Or are you trying to compile and run this? If the later, the compiler will give you a message, if there is a compile-time error. If it is a logic error, then it takes a little more work to find.

Comment: i am getting an error saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at CircleArea.main(CircleArea.java:6)

Comment: Edit the **compilation** error/warning into the question.

Comment: I tried running the same code, it's not giving any error

Comment: Ditto, using `javac` on the commandline, Java 7. Are you using an IDE? What version of Java are you running?